# Can't create GCP Subnet - New subnetwork overlaps with an IP range (172.20.0.0/26) in one of the active peers of an active peer

Tags: mongodb-atlas, google-vpc

I wanted to create subnet with this IP range 172.21.0.0/26 but I failed.
The error says I have overlap with peering network.
The peering network is mongo atlas mongo network.
We have our default VPC peering to atlas mongo VPC.

I don't know why we have this overlapping. All I can see from Mongo atlas console is it's using this cidr 192.168.0.0/16.

And I double checked in my default VPC there're only below subnets of below ip range. There's no overlapping in my default VPC.

172.17.0.0/16
172.18.100.0/28

I want to know, is it overlapping in atlas network and they're using this ip range 172.21.0.0/26 and causing us not able to create subnet ? This is unclear to me totally. I can't see besides 192.168.0.0/16 any other cidrs they use.